# Как распознать объекты(цифры) на картинке/скриншоте python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Я делаю скришнот с помощью библиотеки PIL участка экрана:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно определить баланс по скриншоту. Я планировал это делается с помощью библиотеки `OpenCV(cv2)`
И надо как-то скормить шаблоны по типу этих и двигаться от этого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Решение исключительно из моих предположений)

Если есть более простые решения, то можно их(желательно без ООП и браузер скриптинг не подходит)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [`pytesseract`](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) — обёрткой над [Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

***Пример:***

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('screen.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=9, fy=9)  # Увеличение изображения в 9 раз

# Распознавание, допустимы только цифры
balance = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='outputbase digits')
print(balance)
```

***stdout:***

```py
9897
```

*screen.png:*

[image: Баланс]

Comment: pytesseract выдает ошибку которую у меня не получается исправить(код сначала я решил протестить с этой же картинкой) 

"   Traceback (most recent call last):
...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл.    "

"    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH."

Comment: @DIPPEROK Обратите внимание на то, что `pytesseract` — это только обёртка, и для распознавания Вы должны [установить и сам `tesseract`](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html).